# How to merge two dataframes in Python Pandas, where key column names different, but want to retrieve SOME of the columns from second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge only a couple columns from one dataframe into another, but the key column on both dataframes isn't named correctly.  If you look at the picture "Original two dataframes" Table_1 has the key column "CostCenter" while Table_2 has the key column "CC".  I want the end result to look like the picture titled "New dataframe".  As you can see, I'm only retrieving the "Fixed/Variable" and "CostCenterName" from Table_2 and NOT bringing over the columns "CC", "CostCenterSummary", and "Organization".

Thank you for your help! - Jim

[Original two dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OkVv.png)
[New dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2MSa.png)

Answer (score 0):

first, you can rename your keys of table1:

```
table1.rename(columns={"CostCenter":"CC","CostCenterSummary":"Organization"},inplace = True)
```

then merge tables:

```
result = pd.merge(table1, table2, on=['CC','Organization'])
```

and return your keys :

```
table1.rename(columns={"CC":"CostCenter","Organization":"CostCenterSummary"},inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution to accomplish this: (df1 is Table1 and df2 is Table2 from your screenshot)

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on="CostCenter", right_on="CC")[['CostCenter','CostCenterSummary','Fixed/Variable','CostCenterName']]
```

Prints:

```
   CostCenter CostCenterSummary Fixed/Variable            CostCenterName
0        8308           Finance       Variable       AccountingCorporate
1        8354           Finance       Variable  Accounting International
2        8372           Finance          Fixed        AccountingDomestic
```

Comment: does this help - @Jim?